# how are current location mapped to restaurants in restaurant finder apps android

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, google-maps

I am developing a website and an android app which will show the restaurants near to the current location. I don't know how to map the restaurants in my database.
How it is usually done?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Places API for Android https://developers.google.com/places/android/?hl=en